# integrate text and image inside UI widget

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

hello I would like to know how I can add text and image inside a UI widget I also want it to be without a background please help I want to be able to write my own text and display while I'm writing it.

CSS

```
.thumbs img{
 margin:3px;
width:50px;
float:left;
}
.bottlesWrapper img{
margin:3px;
width:400px;
float:left;
}

#main { border:1px solid #eee; margin:20px; width:410px; height:220px;}
```

**HTML**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>UI widget</title><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="quote" wrap="physical">Enter your favorite quote!</textarea><br />

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id='main'>
<div class="bottlesWrapper">

 <div id="dialog" class="ui-widget-content"> 
     <?


  echo "<i>".$quote."</i><br />";


   ?> 
    </div>

 <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
 </div>

  <div class="thumbs">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180/444" />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />


  </div></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**Script**

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
var thmb = this;
var src  = this.src;
$(thmb).parent('.thumbs').prev('.bottlesWrapper').find('img').fadeout (400,function(){
    thmb.src = this.src;
    $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
   });
   });

   </script>  <script>
   $("#dialog").dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {
    var vDlg = $(event.target).parent();
    var vCont = $('#main');
    vDlg.draggable("option", "containment", vCont).appendTo(vCont);
    $(this).dialog("option", "position", "center");
     }
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/barronfidel7/c1yfj0wv/

Comment: Please indent your code in a uniform matter, as it makes it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/vdsLeqnq/1/).

This is what allows you to see the HTML in the UI widget as you type:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dialog').html($('#quote').val());
  $('#quote').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#dialog').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

While the input has focus, it assigns the HTML of the widget to it's own value after every keyup event.

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for. by any chance do you know how to get rid of the UI but still have the same functions I want to be able to just see the text without the gray bar and also have a transparent background want to move the text and also resize them but if not that is fine I thank you Arleigh Hix

Comment: @johndoe, Just replace the UI container with a div, and if you give it the same `id="dialog"`, then the above JavaScript will still work the same. Just add the desired styles to the div.